# The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, kernel

Whenever I try to import **tensorflow** in my windows machine, its saying that The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically and then its not even working.

The below is the following message given by the jupyter terminal.

Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
Headers are 1.10.1, library is 1.10.2

what could solve this problem.
My version of Python is 3.6.3
and I updated the conda package also.
I have a Windows 10 Machine with 16GB RAM, so it cant be a memory issue also.

I was working with tensorflow previously, but now its not working.

This started to happen like 2 months back! when i was working on my university assignment this happened. The same code was working properly and I ran the code once again on the very same day jupyter notebook it crashed, since then I'm facing this problem.

I also tried to import tensorflow in the command prompt, its still showing the same error.

Has anyone encountered the same problem? What could be the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Message says, `Headers are 1.10.1, library is 1.10.2`

You need to install 1.10.1 version

```
conda install -c anaconda hdf5=1.10.1
```